# InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'

Tags: r, github, r-usethis

I have gone down a rabbit hole trying to set up Github actions to check the builds of my packages via `usethis::use_github_action_check_standard()`. The function fails when it tries to pull the `.yaml` file from the  [r-lib repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/r-lib/actions/master/examples/check-standard.yaml). I am stuck trying to figure out why `readLines()` fails for me. It appears that `readLines()` fails for any files from Github, but does work for files from other locations.

```r
##
## random .txt file works
##
readLines("https://filesamples.com/samples/document/txt/sample1.txt")
#> Warning in readLines("https://filesamples.com/samples/document/txt/
#> sample1.txt"): incomplete final line found on 'https://filesamples.com/samples/
#> document/txt/sample1.txt'
#> [1] "Utilitatis causa amicitia est quaesita."                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#> [2] "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Collatio igitur ista te nihil iuvat. Honesta oratio, Socratica, Platonis etiam. Primum in nostrane potestate est, quid meminerimus? Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quid, si etiam iucunda memoria est praeteritorum malorum? Si quidem, inquit, tollerem, sed relinquo. An nisi populari fama?"
#> [3] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
#> [4] "Quamquam id quidem licebit iis existimare, qui legerint. Summum a vobis bonum voluptas dicitur. At hoc in eo M. Refert tamen, quo modo. Quid sequatur, quid repugnet, vident. Iam id ipsum absurdum, maximum malum neglegi."
#
##
## random .yaml file also works (very long, not showing output)
## 
# readLines("https://wg21.link/index.yaml")

##
## .yaml file from github does not work
##
readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/r-lib/actions/master/examples/check-standard.yaml", encoding = "UTF-8")
#> Warning in file(con, "r"): InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server
#> could not be established'
#> Error in file(con, "r"): cannot open the connection

##
## .txt file from github does not work
##
readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neslib/Neslib.Yaml/master/License.txt")
#> Warning in file(con, "r"): InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server
#> could not be established'
#> Error in file(con, "r"): cannot open the connection
```

I have tried checking and unchecking `Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP` in the RStudio options to no effect.

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who might hit this problem - I lost the  `Warning in file(con, "r"): InternetOpenUrl failed: 'A connection with the server could not be established'` warnings after enabling TLS 1.2:

- Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced tab
- Scroll to Security category, manually check the option box for Use TLS 1.2

Found this solution after getting the same set of errors (as in the question) when using `download.file()`, where the default method for Windows is wininet.dll